# How to generate igraph with known vertex connections and edge weight?

Tags: r, igraph, vertex, edges, weighted-graph

I have already derived vertex connections of the graph. It is a matrix with 3 columns. Column 1 contains vertex i, column 2 contains all its adjacent vertexes, column 3 contains the edge weight, so the data are already processed into something like `{{1,1,0.8} {1, 3, 0.4}, {2, 3, 0.5} ...}`.

Yet I do not know how to incorporate this into igraph in R. Seems to me all presented igraph work are initiated from matrix containing original raw data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in `?"igraph-package"` under the section **Creating graphs**, and you will find the relevant information. In your case, using `graph.data.frame` is sufficient.

```
d <- data.frame(from=c(1, 1, 2), to=c(1, 3, 3), weight=c(0.8, 0.4, 0.5))
graph.data.frame(d)
```